React iframe Works Locally but stops working when published AWS Amplify
We have a React iframe that works locally but stops working when published to AWS Amplify. The iframe is internal to the app but speaks to another apps backend. CORS is not the problem.
We tried pointing to another app external to the app and it works. So all navigation is working. The problem is the page doesn't load and default to the default index page.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
